# Scala function composition: brackets and types

Tags: scala, syntax

**(1)** Having defined two functions in the Scala REPL:

```
scala> def f(s: String) = "f(" + s + ")"
f: (s: String)String

scala> def g(s: String) = "g(" + s + ")"
g: (s: String)String
```

**(2)** Composing them without brackets works as expected:

```
scala> f _ compose g _
res18: String => String = <function1>
```

**(3)** Composing them with brackets doesn't:

```
scala> f(_).compose(g(_))
<console>:14: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => f(x$1).compose(((x$2) => g(x$2))))
       f(_).compose(g(_))
         ^
<console>:14: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$2) => g(x$2))
       f(_).compose(g(_))
                      ^
<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String
 required: Int
       f(_).compose(g(_))
                     ^
```

***Question 1:*** Can somebody explain why?

***Question 2:*** Why the type mismatch? Why is Scala expecting an `Int` at all?

**(4)** Surrounding `f(_)` with brackets seems to help a little bit, by making the first two errors go away:

```
scala> (f(_)).compose(g(_))
<console>:14: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$2) => g(x$2))
       (f(_)).compose(g(_))
                    ^
```

***Question 3:*** Why do these brackets help?

***Question 4:*** Why does Scala need the parameter types, even though they are clearly defined in `f` and `g` respectively?

**(5)** Finally, adding the parameter type makes it work:

```
scala> (f(_)).compose(g(_:String))
res22: String => String = <function1>
```

***Could you please explain what's going on, and provide alternative syntaxes to achieve the composition?***

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can see the (unexpected) expansion using magic show comment:

```
scala> f(_).compose(g(_)) // show
[snip]
      val res0 = ((x$1) => f(x$1).compose(((x$2) => g(x$2))))
```

Function literals need the params constrained, as you showed. `f _` is eta expansion, which is different from `f(_)` which is sugar for `x => f(x)`.

Since the unintended application `f(x$1)` returns a string, which is a `Int => Char` for indexing, you get the added type mismatch.

Underscore is covered by many SO questions, including one canonical.